# flex 1 0 0 vs flex 4 0 0 doesnt take up 1 vs 4 ratio space for flex-flow column;

Tags: javascript, html, css

please kindly fix this.

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.one {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

.four {
  background: red;
  flex: 4 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need `grid`

Comment: @debbugger no you dont. Grid will have the same issue in this case. Grid is needed over flexbox if you want to control both axis at the same time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fill the height, you need to add a `min-height` heigher than the default. By default, the height is calculated to `fit-content`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.one {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

.four {
  background: red;
  flex: 4 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```